# Changing indentation in friggeri CV template

Tags: indentation, templates, friggeri-cv

I am pretty new to latex and currently in the need of writing an CV, so after some googling I found the friggeri CV template (https://github.com/afriggeri/cv), which looked very promising. Unfortunately, I would like it to be a bit more conservative. In other words, I would like to remove the left sidebar, which is easily achieved, and then reduce the indentation of the remaining sections, which I couldn't manage to do yet (Tried some dirty/ugly stuff like addmargin...).

So, in short: How do I reduce the indentation when I remove the side block of the friggeri CV template?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: For the sake of the community, would you be able to supply us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can play with?

Comment: Perhaps the easier route, since you aren't that familiar with LaTeX, is to find a template you prefer. There are a number of options here: https://www.writelatex.com/gallery/tagged/cv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three places you have to change dimensions to reduce the left margin

1. in the geometry layout, specify the left margin
2. in the `\entry` command increase the width of the main text
3. in the side panel reduce the width and move it left

Here is an example doing this making the left margin rather too narrow:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\geometry{left=3cm}
\patchcmd{\entry}{11.8cm}{14.8cm}{}{}
\patchcmd{\aside}{{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)}{{1.6}(0.6, 4.33)}{}{}

\begin{document}
\header{my}{name}
       {latex learner}


% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \section{about}
    16, A Road
    Sometown
    England
    ~
    \href{mailto:me@my.net}{me@my.net}
    \href{http://my.net}{http://my.net}
    \href{http://facebook.com/me}{fb://me}
  \section{languages}
    bilingual english/american
  \section{programming}
    \LaTeX
\end{aside}

\section{interests}

CVs, \LaTeX

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {2006}
    {B.A. {\normalfont some subject}}
    {University of Somewhere}
    {No thesis}
\end{entrylist}

\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {01–03 2009}
    {London}
    {Research Internship.}
    {\emph{Some title.}}
  \entry
    {07–08 2004}
    {XXX}
    {Summer job.}
    {\emph{YYY.}}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

1. is acheived by issuing `\geometry{left=3cm}` from the `geometry` package.  This determines the standard text area on the page.  Originally the value of left is `6.1cm` in this class.
2. is done by patching the command `\entry` increasing the length available by `3cm` from `11.8cm` to `14.8cm`.
3. is done by patching the `aside` environment, or rather its beginning command `\aside`, change the position of the `textblock` from the `textpos` package

The patching command comes from the `etoolbox` package that happens to be loaded already.

You can find documentation for standard packages `geometry`, `textpos`, `etoolbox` etc. either by typing `texdoc` on you system or searching on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org).

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts, this is perfect :)
But since I don't want to use the side block at all, I just had to apply your first two adjustments.

Comment: Dear @AndrewSwann, thanks for your reply.

I tried your solution and in particular number 2, but it doesn't not work. I mean that I added the command:

`\patchcmd{\entry}{11.8cm}{14.8cm}{}{}`

but it doesn't change anything. Any help?

Thank you,
R.

Comment: @user51937 The above was for the version of friggeri-cv.cls from the github page as in the question.  Unfortunately that seems to be have been taken down now.  If you need this for a different version of the class, then you should ask a new question.

Comment: Dear @AndrewSwann, thanks for your reply. I'm talking about the friggeri-cv.cls as mentioned above. I have that version, I downloaded some years ago.

Comment: @user51937 I no longer have copy of that file.  If you send it to me via email, you can find the address on my homepage linked to from my profile here, then I will have a look at it.

Comment: Dear @AndrewSwann, thank you again for helping me! I decided to take you suggestion and I posted a new question in the forum, here the [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338397/changing-tabular-alignment-in-friggeri-cv): 
 thank you, R.