# Changing the width of second page and so on in friggeri cv, keeping first intact?

Tags: xetex, margins, indentation, document-classes, friggeri-cv

Lots of people are interested in this at different places, but I couldn't find a direct solution. One can use the template from [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv).

A part of it is answered here and a simple tweak would be to reduce the page width via geometry package as `\geometry{left=1cm}`

[Changing indentation in friggeri CV template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197912/changing-indentation-in-friggeri-cv-template)

But what I want is to issue this command only from the second page and so-forth, for the first page it should respect the default margins and whenever text flows to second page, its get wider to page width.

I am using \newpage to manually define which sections should go on to the second page, as side page is a waste on the second page.

Could someone help me on this?
Have a good day!

Comment: Perhaps this question may help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209887/emulating-article-class-margins-with-the-geometry-package

Comment: Thanks Steven for the hint, I will write the answer up in terms of what I did, it solved it :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Steven for the hint and reference [Emulating article class margins with the geometry package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209887/emulating-article-class-margins-with-the-geometry-package)

`pass` is the key which keeps the original settings and also allows to create a new command with custom options.

I added `pass` parameter to the `geometry` package and after the `\newpage` and I did setup the custom margin via `\newgeomtery` command

```
\newgeometry{margin=1in,top=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm}
```

Additional Tip: After custom margins, reduce the width between the two columns of the sections via `\patchcmd{\entry}{11.8cm}{14.8cm}{}{}`

Details : [Changing indentation in friggeri CV template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197912/changing-indentation-in-friggeri-cv-template)