# Changing tabular alignment in Friggeri CV

Tags: tables, indentation, friggeri-cv

I'm actually dealing with the Friggeri CV.
This template uses friggeri-cv.cls as class file.
In this file you can find everything you need to customize the final CV.

The CV is divided in parts: structure, list environment, side block, super side block, super side NEW PAGE, bibliography. The structure and list environment use actually the tabular package.

I want to change the left indentation of the structure part, moving the whole part to the left. Here an image of what I tried to explain:

[image: friggeri template left indentation]

I would be grate to you guys if someone helps me.

Thank you,
R.

EDIT: providing the MWE and the output

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}

\begin{document}

\header{NAME}{SURNAME}{JOB TITLE}
\begin{textblock*}{300pt}(30pt, 0.75pt)
\includegraphics[width=0.325\textwidth]{photo/picture}
\end{textblock*}


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{interests}

\textbf{professional:} bus taking, wall jumping  \\
\textbf{personal:} donuts eating


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2009--2011}
{Master's Degree {\normalfont DEGREE}   {\small \textcolor{gray}{4/4}}}
{UNIVERSITY}
{\emph{{\small TITLE}}}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2005--2009}
{Bachelor's Degree {\normalfont DEGREE}     {\small \textcolor{gray}{4/4}}}
{UNIVERSITY}
{\emph{{\small TITLE}}}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2016}
{Office}
{New York}
{\emph{\textit{Post-lauream} internship to achieve} \\
Learned how..
\begin{itemize}
\item Able to
\item Able to 
\item Able to
\end{itemize}}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2013}
{Office}
{Boston}
{\emph{\textit{Post-lauream} internship regarding the} \\
Obtained tangible improvements in..
\begin{itemize}
\item Able to
\item Able to
\item Able to  
\end{itemize}}

 \end{entrylist}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS APPLICATIONS
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{applications}

\begin{entrylist}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2012}
{Achieved scholarship for}
{ORGANIZATION}
{description}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

2nd EDIT: adding part of the .cls in order to accomplish the tabular spacing

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% List environment %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[5]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{12.5cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

I posted this code because, looking at the last image I added, I want to modify (increase) the blank space between **MASTER'S DEGREE 4/4** and **UNIVERSITY**. I think that I need to modify the tabular*{}{} arguments. I don't know how.

Thanks again,
R.

Comment: Although *TeX documents produce visual output, the basis of the document and of this site is the code that produces the output. But you have provided neither..?

Comment: Choosig a template means choosing a layout. The layout is mant to be fixed. A change like that means rewriting the complete class file, You would be better off to start from scratch.

Comment: Also, you did not say which template you are using. People have the bad habit of thinking they own a file and can change it however they want. That is the reason we have several diferent *friggerri* templates out there. It is a real mess. [A similar example](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/exampleDeedyResume.md)

Comment: Dear @jon, thank you for your answer, I appreciate your help!

Sorry if I didn't include the MWE, I though it was unnecessary for this kind of question, my fault. Anyway, I made a MWE and I shared the output it produces by editing my original post.

Let me know if it can help.
Thank you again,
R.

Comment: Dear @Johannes_B, thank you for your answer! I'm using the friggeri cv, I think that everything comes already in that friggeri-cv.cls file (but probably I'm just blaspheming!).

Anyway, I think that the creative commons license purpose is to distribute a file (for example) and then let people do whatever (legal) they want to do with that. LateX is super powerful in the meaning that, if you are able to, you can modify whatever you want in the way you want!..............

Comment: @Johannes_B ....................Starting from a scratch (of someone else which had a great idea) one can write the code to best perform its own task. Isn't it?

Here I don't have the whole competences to do whatever I want to do with the friggeri file, then I asked to you guys (the most important LateX gurus in the world) to help me. Only that :-)

Thank you again,
R.

Comment: But where is the `.cls` file? As @Johannes_B says, there are probably many different versions of this class file around. (It would be nice it it were uploaded to CTAN so there was a definitive version.) Note: I think there is a missing `\end{entrylist}` in the `experience` section.

Comment: You should also use an example `.tex` file that includes the lefthand part.

Comment: Dear @jon, thanks again for your answer. Yes, I forgot a \end{entrylist}. I downloaded some years ago the friggeri-cv package from latextemplates.com. I can send you the .cls if you prefer, but I already know in which section of the .cls is written the code to modify the indentation. I just don't know how to handle with it! I didn't get what do you mean with "lefthand part" :-) Thank you, R.

Comment: `\geometry{left=2cm}`

Comment: The thing is, you say you are working with `friggeri.cls`, but because everybody is allowed to alter it, we have different versions of friggeri template all over the place. That is why even the C-Commons people say: Don't use a CC liense for software. And any free license like GPL or MIT or Apache is nice for software developers, but a real nightmare for LaTeX helpers, as a LaTeX class file isn't really software but  defined layout and macros provided. That is why LaTeX has its very own LPPL.

Comment: Thank you @Johannes_B! Unfortunately the \geometry{left=2cm} changes the geometry of the whole document, which doesn't mean to be the right solution. I understand what you wrote about the numerous versions of the friggeri.cls, in the version I have the solutions is in the LIST ENVIRONMENT and in the STRUCTURE sections, I'm sure about that. R.

Comment: Please try again.

Comment: If you think your version is important, you might want to share which version you have. Luckily, i have access to *all* different versions ever published by the template site.

Comment: Dear @Johannes_B, I have the version [2012/04/30 CV class]

Comment: I don't blame you, please don't think that. But in these days, this is not helpful. Please have a look at [aother example](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/exampleDeedyResume.md) to undderstand why. Which template version do you have?  Is it `1.2`. The proposed change works perfectly, that's why i was asking you to try again.

Comment: As @Johannes_B says, you likely need to change the `geometry` settings (however, `left=2cm` surely would only work if that sideblock in the topmost image is not being use..?). Now, here's the thing: if you are going to change the `.cls` file itself, you really should change the `.cls` name, too. It is just a disaster that there are (or if there are) many `friggeri.cls` files floating around! Do not contribute to the (as it were) [confusio classium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_of_tongues)!

Comment: @Johannes_B, I don't mind any kind of philosophical or ethical or whatever reason to do or not do something. I want to get the result. Chatting about the reason for or the consequence of, does not represent my actual point of view, above all in a internet forum.
I want to solve the problem and I'm quite near: I indented the whole \entry block in a \begin{textblock} and it works like a charme. Now I have just some problems with the right margin, BUT not the right margin of the document, the right margin of the TABULAR.
Believe me guys, geometry doesn't apply here. Look at the .cls

Comment: And @jon, I will never share my friggeri_modified.cls, promised.
I will not contribute to the entropy increase of the friggeri's file in the web world.

Comment: Every version of `friggeri.cls` I've seen uses the `geometry` package to set the textblock. I suspect this is the easiest and best way to accomplish your goal. But you have not shown us the `.cls` file you are using, so it is impossible to give useful & definitive advice....  (Note: it's not about the 'sharing' of the class, it's that people share without renaming. You should consider renaming yours in a way that is unlikely to be named the same way as someone else's modified version. So, not `friggeri_modified.cls`, but, say, `friggeri_user51937.cls`.)

Comment: Dear @jon, I edited again my original post. Now there's the part of the .cls which I need to modify and the reason why. Thank you, R.

Comment: I'm sorry, but does the package load `geometry`? If it does, changing the `tabular` material  is probably hacking a 'fix' into place that fights against more global settings rather than simply fixing the global settings.

Comment: This line, `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}` in fact shows that the `tabular` is designed to take up the entire `textwidth`, which is set by `geometry, either explicitly or implicitly. Therefore, you need to modify `geometry` (or the equivalent).

Comment: Changing the left margin works perfectly fine with all versions published on LaTeXtemplates.com. Since the OP obviously knows where to find an answer and is telling us so, i don't see a reason why i should look at this any further.

Comment: Change the width of the parbox.

Comment: Ehi guys, by **both** changing the `left margin geometry`, the width of the `parbox` and the width of the `textblock` we got the result! THANK YOU very much guys!